# wpf File Explorer change name of file inside ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

Hello I have a model called `FileDirectoryModel` and it contains:

```
   public class FileDirectoryModel
    {
        public string imgPath { get; set; }
        public string DirPath { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string size { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modifed { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
```

I also have a ListView :

```
   <ListView x:Name="lstExplorer"
              Background="White"
              ItemsSource="{Binding DirectoryCollection}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}"
              >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FileExplorerClickCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                                Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="{Binding imgPath}"
                                       Height="20"
                                       Width="20"
                                       Stretch="Fill"/>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="explorerText"
                                         Text="{Binding FileName}">
                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="50">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <TextBlock Text="Size" />                            
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding size}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <TextBlock Text="Type" />
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileType}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Width="100">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader>
                        <TextBlock Text="Modifed" />
                    </GridViewColumnHeader>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Modifed}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and `DirectoryCollection` is :

```
    private ObservableCollection<FileDirectoryModel> _DirectoryCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<FileDirectoryModel> DirectoryCollection
    {
        get { return _DirectoryCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (_DirectoryCollection != value)
            {
                _DirectoryCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a dubbleclick command that will open the file that is selected but I'm having a hard time trying yo figure out how to allow someone to change the name of the selected item.

Please note that I saw [File ListView, Change name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200155/file-listview-change-name-direct-in-listview-wpf-c-sharp-mvvm) which doesn't apply because they are telling how to change the file name not how to have xaml allow the change.

Comment: this might help.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207888/wpf-listview-detect-when-selected-item-is-clicked
just make sure to check mousedoubleclick count arg in the event handle to 2

Comment: how do you bind to allow edits only on selected record?

Comment: what do you mean by edit ? edit fields like datagrid do?

Comment: no, the name field is a textbox but I want it locked where nobody can change the name except certain people.

Comment: Do you want to have inline edit in list box column? so that allowed people can do inline edit directly.

Comment: When you open  a file, do you open a file using default application through Process.Start or you open in another window which shows the content and properties (like Name) of the file?

Comment: I use process.Start on everything but PDFs. They open inside another usercontrol.

Comment: Yes, I want an Inline Edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to setup a CommandParameter to pass get the name of the double clicked item.

```
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FileExplorerClickCommand}"
     CommandParameter="{Binding}/>
</i:EventTrigger>
```

The FileDirectoryModel item that was double clicked will get passed to the FileExplorerClickCommand method (you will need to change the method params. You can then perform whatever you need on that item.